# script to build frequency word pairs on 100 mln DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, frequency

Please help me to build word pairs frequency table from table with 100 mln records that is work on SQL Server 2008 db. 
Table looks like:

```
Original table 
id |source |comment(255)
-------------------
1     A1     review budget limitation
```

source is some ID that has could have about 800 different values. Distribution of sources in original table is exponential. That means amount of records with source A1 could be 20 mln and A500 is only 10,000.

In final I would like to get a word pairs frequency table with ignoring words: 
the, and, of, to, a, i, it, in, or, is

How I expected it should work (I could be not optimal here):

1. read first two words from comment in original table, put it to FREQUENCY
2. read next two words and put it

Frequency table

```
id | word pairs        | source |Frequency
 ---------------------------------------------
1   review budget         A1         1
2   budget limitation     A1         1
```

1. Fill in full comment from first record that has for example source A1
2. Start next record and process it in the same way.
3. If it found same word pairs already exist in Frequency table and source is the same than just increment Frequency, if source is different - add this pair with new source.

Please help me with optimal sql script for SQL Server ?

Comment: What is the maximum number of words you can have in comment?

Comment: comments limited in 255 symbols.

Comment: How many words among those symbols?  In your example, you have three.

Comment: Gordon, it depends, but i rough estimate about 20 - 30 words

Comment: Do you need all pairs or just adjacent pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll work this out in a minute (given time) but I'd like to put forth two imperatives:

- Anything that needs to be done fast in SQL needs to be done set-based. Avoid processing things "one at a time".
- Use a table valued function to split up the comments into a table of word pairs
- Use Common Table Expressions to layer your work to keep things readable

With these three rules you can move tons of data. After you built the select-statement it's just a matter of dumping it into a table.

**EDIT:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitToPairs(@sText nvarchar(255))
RETURNS @Pairs TABLE (
    Pair nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @sText = LTRIM(RTRIM(@sText));
    DECLARE @Pos1 int = 0
    DECLARE @Pos2 int = CHARINDEX(' ', @sText);
    DECLARE @Pos3 int;
    IF @Pos2 <> 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Word1 nvarchar(255) = SUBSTRING(@sText, @Pos1+1, @Pos2-@Pos1-1);
        WHILE CHARINDEX(N'|' + @Word1 + N'|', N'|the|and|of|to|a|i|it|in|or|is|') <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Pos1 = @Pos2;
            SET @Pos3 = CHARINDEX(' ', @sText, @Pos2+1);
            SET @Pos2 = @Pos3;
            SET @Word1 = SUBSTRING(@sText, @Pos1+1, @Pos2-@Pos1-1);
        END
        DECLARE @Word2 nvarchar(255);

        WHILE @Pos2 <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Pos3 int = CHARINDEX(' ', @sText, @Pos2+1);
            IF @Pos3 <> 0
            BEGIN
                SET @Word2 = SUBSTRING(@sText, @Pos2+1, @Pos3-@Pos2-1);
                WHILE CHARINDEX(N'|' + @Word2 + N'|', N'|the|and|of|to|a|i|it|in|or|is|') <> 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @Pos1 = @Pos2;
                    SET @Pos2 = @Pos3;
                    SET @Word2 = SUBSTRING(sText, @Pos2+1, @Pos2-@Pos1-1);
                END
                INSERT @Pairs (Pair) VALUES (@Word1 + N' ' + @Word2)
            END

            SET @Pos1 = @Pos2;
            SET @Pos2 = @Pos3;
            SET @Word1 = @Word2;
        END
    END
    -- Note: if only one word in text, no insert happens
    RETURN @Pairs
END
```

Then, use that to build a select

```
SELECT I.Source, P.Pair, COUNT(*) AS Frequency
FROM Information AS I CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitToPairs(i.Comment) AS P
GROUP BY I.Source, P.Pair
```

It's possible that I'm off by some edge case, but it should give you an idea of what I'm going for.
It also doesn't consider "word1 word2" and "word2 word1" to be equal.

I leave that as an exercise to the reader :p

**EDIT:**

Added `TABLE` keyword on `RETURNS` line.

Also, assigning a value in the `DECLARE` only works starting from SQL 2008 I think..

**EDIT:**

Added `RETURN` statement

**EDIT:**

Changes per AntarticIce's feedback

Comment: wow, that's nice! I faced with trying to create function.  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SplitToPairs, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.  
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SplitToPairs, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near 'int'.  
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure SplitToPairs, Line 32
Must declare the table variable "@Pairs".

Comment: You MAY be able to replace the function with some fancy regex or text querying. But I'm not well versed enough in those. The main tool here is really using CROSS APPLY to split your comment into pairs and then grouping and counting that set.

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh You're correct about not being able to declare and assign to values on the same line until SQL 2008 - this didn't work on 2005.

Comment: Guys, I have 2008R2 and this works here. I added RETURN before last  End to successfully create above function

Comment: Meh, there's still something wrong with it. My "skip word if it's one of ...." code needs to find the new pos3 first. As it is, I leave the change to AntarticIce :p. My work shift is over.

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh Thanks, it works! I made only few corrections.  1. Added    SET Pos3 = CHARINDEX(' ', sText, Pos2+1); before setting    SET Pos2 = Pos3; in first block of skipping words.   2. Corrected positions in second skipping block    SET Word2 = SUBSTRING(sText, Pos2+1, Pos2-Pos1-1);  Could you please update it ? Maybe it would help others! Thanks again!